# Ejs - templating data is not rendering

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am getting issue to render my data to the html using 'ejs' template engine. Any one can help me please..?

When user goes to `app.get('/', userList.list);`

I am calling the function:

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next){
  dataList.find({}, function(error, users){ // users consoles correctly.
    var locals = {};
    if(error) return next(error);
    res.render('index', // this is file name. is it wrong?
        {   name:name,
            dept:dept
        }
    );
  });
};
```

here is my index.ejs:

```
<body>
    <h1>Please Add your Details</h1>
    <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
        <div class="photo">
          <h2><%=user.name%></h2>
          <p>Department Is : <%= user.dept %></p>
        </div>
      <% }) %>
</body>
```

But nothing rendering in the page. what is wrong? any one help me. I am a beginner for this 'ejs' template and node.

Comment: Have you set the 'views' directory?

Comment: yes. I did. without passing the object it's works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all,

It works for me:

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next){
  dataList.find({}, function(error, users){
    var locals = {};
    if(error) return next(error);
    res.render('index',{users:users,title:'how to render?'});
  });
};
```